# How can you do subtraction of 2 SQL fields to output in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and SQL and I am stuck and I am not sure where to look. I have 3 columns, `end_odometer`, `start_odometer` and `km_travel`. The user inputs the start and end values in a Laravel page and I wish to subtract the `end_odometer` from the `start_odometer` and store that in the `km_travel`.

This is my store controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $count= new VehicleLog();
        $count->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
        $count->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');


        $count->save();
        return redirect('/resulttravel')->with('success', 'data added');
    }
```

I am not sure what the `km_travel` code should entail. If someone could push me in the right direction, that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what about `$count->km_travel = $request->input('start_odo') - $request->input('end_odo');` ?

Comment: `$count->km_travel = $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo');`, you need to  do END - START. because if odometer start from 5000 and end on 5010 then km should be 10 so. 5010-5000 = 10

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you can do like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $count= new VehicleLog();
    $count->start_odo = $request->input('start_odo');
    $count->end_odo = $request->input('end_odo');
    $count->km_travel = $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo');
    $count->save();
    return redirect('/resulttravel')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```

Or:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    VehicleLog::create([
        'start_odo' => $request->input('start_odo'),
        'end_odo' => $request->input('end_odo'),
        'km_travel' => $request->input('end_odo') - $request->input('start_odo')
    ]);
    return redirect('/resulttravel')->with('success', 'data added');
}
```